# How to install pushd, popd commands for MacOS?

Tags: macos

Tried `brew search pushd`, `brew search popd`, no dice. OS version MacOS 10.12 Sierra.

Answer (score 2):

I have no OSX Sierra but `pushd` and `popd` are usually [builtins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_builtin), not commands. If you miss them, then you shell does not provide them.
Also, usually OSX fires a graphical message when attempting to use a command which is not yet installed but supported and tells you how to install it.

You can still create your own fully-compatible shell functions to handle that.

Answer (score 0):

On [macOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS), `pushd` and `popd` are builtin shell commands. This explains why nothing is returned if you try to find them using `which pushd` or `which popd`. Issuing any of the following three commands will bring up the same [man page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page) listing the shell builtin commands. However, that man page does not list the usage for `pushd` and `popd`.

```bsh
man builtin
man popd
man pushd
```

To see the usage for `pushd` or `popd` use the following commands. (Note, do not type the `$` as that simply represents the shell command prompt.)

```bsh
$ pushd -h
-bash: pushd: -h: invalid number
pushd: usage: pushd [dir | +N | -N] [-n]
$ popd -h
bash: popd: -h: invalid number
popd: usage: popd [+N | -N] [-n]
```

Answer (score 0):

The commands are default on the Mac.

NOTE: The commands pushd/popd  need to be preceded by a mkdir of some sort.